# error while Changing the mac address using a python script

Tags: wireless-networking, python

getting errors while executing the program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
subprocess.call("ifconfig wlan0 down", shell=True)
subprocess.call("ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:55", shell=True)
subprocess.call("ifconfig wlan0 up", shell=True)

SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
SIOCSIFHWADDR: Operation not permitted
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
```

What does it mean and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you running it as root or switching to root with `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

Your Python code will work fine if you are logged in as root, But if you are not you need use “sudo” before “ifconfig”